Number of Singular Fibres in map $\operatorname{Bl}_{C_1\cap C_2} \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^1$
The Euler characteristics are topological (except for $\chi(\mathcal{O}_C)$).
Let $C_1, C_2$ be two degree $d$ plane curves given by polynomials $f_1,f_2$. Then they span a pencil $P = \mathbb{P}^1_{[u:v]} \subset |\mathcal{O}(d)|$. There is a map
$$ \mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 $$
given by taking a point $[x:y:z]$ to $[u:v]$ corresponding to the unique curve $u\cdot f_1 + v \cdot f_2$ passing through $[x:y:z]$. This map is rational as it is defined everywhere except for $C_1 \cap C_2$. Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ at $C_1 \cap C_2$. Then there is a map $$\Gamma \to \mathbb{P}^1$$ by composing $\Gamma \to \mathbb{P}^2$ with the map above.
Assuming that all singular fibres have at most one singular point and it is a node, I want to compute the number of singular fibres. I tried the following, but I seem to get a wrong answer. I would appreciate if anyone could point me into the right direction.
FACTS used:

$\chi(\mathbb{P}^n) = n+1$.
For a plane curve $C$ of degree $d$, $\chi^\mathrm{top} (C) = 2\chi(\mathcal{O}_C) = 3d - d^2$.
For a fibration $E\to B$ with fibre $F$, $\chi(E) = \chi(B) \cdot \chi(F)$.
For a nodal plane curve $C'$ of degree $d$ with one node, $\chi^\mathrm{top} (C') = 3d-d^2 +1$.
Blowing up $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a smooth point increases the topological Euler characteristic by $1$.

Using FACT #3 in our case,
$$ \chi(\Gamma) = (\chi(\mathbb{P}^1) - \mu) \cdot \chi(F) + \mu \cdot \chi(F'),$$
where $\mu$ is the number of singular fibres, $F$ is a generic fibre, and $F'$ is a singular fibre.
We compute using facts #1, #2, #3, and #4:
$$ \chi(\Gamma) = (2-\mu) \cdot (3d-d^2) + \mu \cdot (3d-d^2-1) = 6d -2d^2 + \mu.$$
On the other hand using facts #1 and #5,
$$ \chi(\Gamma) = \chi(\mathbb{P}^2 ) +d^2  = 3+ d^2.$$
But then, according to that,
$$ \mu = 6d - 3d^2 -3.$$
This is negative for $d \geq 2$.

The pencil $ X = V(uf_1 + vf_2) \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 $ is the blow-up of $ \mathbb{P}^2 $ at $ C_1 \cap C_2 $. Let $ \mu $ be the number of singular fibres, all assumed to have exactly one singularity, a node. Then counting $ \chi_{top}(X) $ using the pencil $ X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 $ gives $ \chi_{top}(X) = (2-\mu) (2-2g) + \mu (3-2g) = 4(1-g) + \mu $ where $ g = (d-1)(d-2)/2 $ is the genus of a smooth curve in the pencil. On the other hand, counting $ \chi_{top}(X) $ using the blow-up $ X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2 $ gives $ \chi_{top}(X) = 3 + d^2 $
So $ \mu = 3 + d^2 - 4 + 2(d-1)(d-2) = 3d^2 -6d + 3 $ which is always non-negative as $ \mu = 3(d-1)^2 $

There is a mistake in the first computation of $\chi(\Gamma)$. It is equal to $$ 6d - 2d^2 +\mu.$$ Therefore, $\mu = -6d +3d^2 +3$.
